# How do I solve the error - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

```
delaylevel <- c()
delaysort <- function(delaycol){
  for (x in delaycol){
    if (x > 60){
      append(delaylevel, 3)
    }else if (x > 30){
      append(delaylevel, 2)
    }else if (x > 15){
      append(delaylevel, 1)
    }else{
      append(delaylevel, 0)
    }
  }
}

sapply(flights$ARRIVAL_DELAY, delaysort)
```

`flights$ARRIVAL_DELAY` is a column from a data frame (vector). I am able to apply each element individually to get a TRUE or FALSE, but it does not work with this function. What should be changed to make the fuction work?

Comment: Hi, your if statements are creating an integer (0:3). How is this meant to create a TRUE/FALSE? Can you show some example data (in code format) and your expected output?

Comment: You'll need to give an example of the data that causes the error, for example `sapply(1:70, delaysort)` doesn't cause an error (although the output doesn't look correct either, being a list of `NULL`s

Comment: Hi, the data that causes an error is the column flights$ARRIVAL_DELAY - this column is a vector of integers, thus doing a for loop for each of its elements and creating a TRUE/FALSE by applying flights$ARRIVAL_DELAY[x] > 60 should not be an issue. However, this is the error that I keep getting : Error in if (flights$ARRIVAL_DELAY[x] > 60) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency aside... you need to assign after you use append() and then also return the result from the function:

```
delaysort <- function(delaycol){
  delaylevel <- c()
  for (x in delaycol){
    if (x > 60){
      delaylevel = append(delaylevel, 3)
    }else if (x > 30){
      delaylevel = append(delaylevel, 2)
    }else if (x > 15){
      delaylevel = append(delaylevel, 1)
    }else{
      delaylevel = append(delaylevel, 0)
    }
  }
  return(delaylevel)
}

sapply(1:70, delaysort)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

A faster and more R'ish would be using cut or similar:

```
delaysort <- function(delaycol) as.integer(cut(1:70, c(0, 15, 30, 60, Inf))) - 1
delaysort(delaycol)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```